# How to add path aliases to Storybook webpack configuration?

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, storybook

I am using Storybook with nextjs and webpack. Here's my `.storybook/main.ts`:

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/nextjs';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  ...
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/nextjs',
    options: {},
  },
  ...
};

export default config;
```

This combination automatically picks up TypeScript settings from `tsconfig.json` of this workspace – which is very nice. I am trying to add some TypeScript path aliases just for Storybook. I tried the following based on several SO answers, but it is not working –Storybook gives errors whenever it encounters imports from paths like this `@/components`.

```
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  ...
  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    if (config.resolve) {
      config.resolve.alias = {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        '@/*': [
          './src/*',
          '../../packages/ui-lib/src/*',
        ],
      };
    }

    return config;
  },
};
```

If I put the same aliases in my tsconfig.json, Storybook works. However I don't want to do that because the tsconfig for this workspace should know nothing about source code in `ui-lib` folder.

Any ideas why this is not working?

P.S. I also tried specifying paths like this: `path.resolve(__dirname, "../../packages/ui-lib/src")` - that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin?

I encountered a similar problem and solved it like this:

```bash
yarn add -D tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin
npm install -D tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin
```

```js
//main.ts
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-webpack5";

const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");

const config: StorybookConfig = {
 //...
   webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    if (config.resolve) {
      config.resolve.plugins = [
        ...(config.resolve.plugins || []),
        new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
          extensions: config.resolve.extensions,
        }),
      ]
    }
    return config;
  },
}
```